# Make a program in C to show all existing prime numbers between two natural numbers

Tags: c

Make a program in C to show all existing prime numbers between two natural numbers that will be entered and that will define a closed range, ie the numbers entered are included in the range.

```
main ()
{
    int R, CR, i, a, N;
    for (i=0;1<10;i++){
        printf("\nENTER NUMBER: ");
        scanf("%i",&N);
        if (N<0){
        printf("\nINVALID NUMBER!");
    }
        CR=0;
        for (a=1;a<=N;a++){
            R=N%a;
            if(R==0) CR=CR+1;
        }
        if(CR==2) printf("\n%2.i It's Cousin", N);
        else printf("\n%i NOT COUSIN");
    }

system ("pause");
}
```

how i do it?

The numbers entered must be integers and the program should test whether each number entered is greater than 0. If the number entered does not meet this condition, it should loop to number

Always show displayed messages on screen, both in the incoming order and when showing results

Comment: I guess you should start by entering two numbers to define a range, as requested by the task. But before you go any further, you are missing `#include <stdio.h>` and the function `main` should be defined as `int main(void)`.

Comment: #include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void main ()

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It is not very clear what you are asking. May I suggest you take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Also make sure you read any feedback carefully - we don't write `main ()` or `void main ()` any more.

Comment: The program you have posted seems unrelated to the problem, e.g., you are reading only one number instead of range. Did you just post some other program and hope that it will persuade us to do your homework?

Comment: I understand, I just wanted to complete this activity because I'm not getting. that sad
 :(

Comment: https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/examples/prime-number-intervals

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a, b;
    //takes the two input numbers
    printf("Enter the two numbers\n");
    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
    //checks if the entered number is invalid
    if((a < 0) || (b < 0))
    {
        printf("Invalid numbers");
        return -1;
    }
    //for each number between a and b, checks either it is prime or not
    for(int i = a; i <= b; i++)
    {
        int count = 0;
        //counts the number of divisors of the number i with remainder 0
        for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        {
            if(i % j == 0)
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
        //if number of divisors of the i is less than 3, which means the 
        //number is prime, it prints the number
        if(count < 3)
        {
            printf("%d ", i);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```